# How to apply a custom fuction with rolling on groups in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'date':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ,'open':[4,5,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'close':[4,5,6,7,8,1,2,9,10,11],'stock':['A']*5 + ['B']*5})

df['flag'] = np.select([df['close']>df['open'],df['close']<df['open']],['up','down'],default='flat')
df
```

|  | date | open | close | stock | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 4 | A | flat |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 5 | A | flat |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 6 | A | up |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 7 | A | up |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | 8 | A | up |
| 5 | 6 | 6 | 1 | B | down |
| 6 | 7 | 7 | 2 | B | down |
| 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 | B | up |
| 8 | 9 | 9 | 10 | B | up |
| 9 | 10 | 10 | 11 | B | up |

I tried the following. None of them works. They all give me "No numeric types to aggregate" error

```
# flag if previous 3 days (t-2,t-1, and t) are all increase for each stock

df['3days_up'] = df.groupby('stock')['flag'].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if all(x['flag']=='up') else 'No')
df['3days_up'] = df.groupby('stock')[['flag']].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if all(x['flag']=='up') else 'No')
df['3days_up'] = df.groupby('stock').rolling(3).apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if all(x['flag']=='up') else 'No')
```

Expected output:

|  | date | open | close | stock | flag | 3days_up |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 4 | A | flat | No |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 5 | A | flat | No |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 6 | A | up | No |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 7 | A | up | No |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | 8 | A | up | Yes |
| 5 | 6 | 6 | 1 | B | down | No |
| 6 | 7 | 7 | 2 | B | down | No |
| 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 | B | up | No |
| 8 | 9 | 9 | 10 | B | up | No |
| 9 | 10 | 10 | 11 | B | up | Yes |

Comment: you could always map up = 1, down = 0, apply a rolling sum and map values of 3 to Yes, and all others to No

Comment: @Riley thanks. Just wonder why the string comparison doesn't work though? Is all( str == "Up") part wrong or any other parts have problem?

Comment: rolling windows on non numerical data doesn't seem to be implemented https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23002

Comment: As @Riley said, rolling on non numeric values is not possible. You have to convert your column as numeric.

Comment: Oh thats sad!! Does that mean I cant even do something simple like concat last 3 rows strings? @Corralien

Comment: You are totally right...

Comment: Sadly it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. I guess a simple for-loop would be the last resort

Comment: if you wanted to do something like concat strings over rolling window then take a different approach where you create two Series - one shifted 2 places, one shifted one place. There are lots of examples on how to concat columns of strings here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `up` value to `True` and others to `False` as starting point:

```
df['3days_up'] = np.where(df.assign(is_up=df['flag'] == 'up')
                            .groupby('stock').rolling(3)['is_up']
                            .sum() >= 3, 'Yes', 'No')
print(df)

# Output
   date  open  close stock  flag 3days_up
0     1     4      4     A  flat       No
1     2     5      5     A  flat       No
2     3     3      6     A    up       No
3     4     4      7     A    up       No
4     5     5      8     A    up      Yes
5     6     6      1     B  down       No
6     7     7      2     B  down       No
7     8     8      9     B    up       No
8     9     9     10     B    up       No
9    10    10     11     B    up      Yes
```